# retrieve 1 variable in array of my controller

Tags: arrays, angular, laravel, httpclient

My controller return an array of variables.

```
    return response()->json([$newBauxEnCours, $bienPrixEnBaisse]);
```

My method for call API Laravel

```
 getProducts(status: string, typeTransac: string): Observable <any> {

        let params = new HttpParams();

    params = params.append('status', status);
    params = params.append('typeTransac', typeTransac);

    console.log(params);
    
    if (status !== null && typeTransac !== null) {
    // Conversion en nombre 
    return this.apiClient.get(this.ApiUrl, { params: params});
    }else{
        console.log('aucune valeur en params')
    }
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.ArchiveVente$ = this.dataMlsService.getProducts('Vendu', 'Vente');
    console.log(this.ArchiveVente$);
  }
```

My problem is : Why retrieve my variable $newBauxEnCours in Angular ?

Thanks

Comment: you need subscribe to an observable to get the values. https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular and next

Comment: The English is a little rough here, which is OK :). What does "return this.apiClient.get(this.ApiUrl, { params: params});" return?

Comment: Eliseo, i can't use Async Pipe ??? 
ahah Kurt. I practice speaking English without using the translator.(im sry) This return is an API call

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.dataMlsService.getProducts('Vendu', 'Vente').subscribe((response: any)=> {
     console.log(response);
    });
   
  }
```

Comment: I use AsynPipe so i can't subcribe i think ??
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],.......

Comment: try this statement  ```console.log(response);``` instead of ```console.log(this.ArchiveVente$);```. Answer edited please check.

Comment: ngOnInit(){
    this.dataMlsService.getProducts('Vendu', 'Vente').subscribe((res:any)=>
    {
      console.log(res);
    });
(2) [Array(8), Array(784)]

Comment: yes now you got the the data whatever you are fetching from api.

Answer (score 0):

GetProducts returns this.apiClient.get() which returns a Observable. The Observable will not get executed until you subscribe to it.

Because the get call is asynchronous you must provide a function (callback) to the subscribe function that will get called when the get is finished.

```
this.ArchiveVente$ = this.dataMlsService.getProducts('Vendu', 'Vente').subscribe((response: any)=> {
 console.log(response);
});
```

this.ArchiveVente$ is set to the observable. in your html you need to use it with the async pipe. e.g.

```
<li *ngFor="let varName of ArchiveVente$ | async">
 {{ varName.name }}
</li>
```

you can also just add the data to the variable than you can use is without the async pipe

```
this.dataMlsService.getProducts('Vendu', 'Vente').subscribe((response: any)=> {
    this.ArchiveVente = response; 
});
```

see: https://angular.io/guide/observables for more info

Comment: the thing is, i wish do most API call.
 ngOnInit(){
    this.dataMlsService.getProducts('Vendu', 'Vente'),
    this.dataMlsService.getProducts('value 3', 'value 4'),
    this.dataMlsService.getProducts('value 5', 'Value 6'),

Comment: Than you can use forkJoin. See: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin for more information